# How to use XIB in a Swift project iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xib

I had two separate Xcode projects that I have fused into a single one: a speech to text recognizer that is implemented with a XIB file, written in Objective-C, and another project that is just a conventional UI written in Swift with some more stuff. Both projects work flawlessly by themselves.
I have cleaned out all the errors, and created a Bridging header file. So far, both Swift and Objective-C modules coexist, but obviously only the Swift part runs.
I want to open the Objective-C XIB and display it in my swift-coded UI.

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: What is "conventional UI" (relative to a XIB file)?  Why is it so obvious that only the Swift part runs?

Comment: @conventional means that it has a button, a textbox, some sort of hello world functionality.... coded in swift. It runs well for the little it does. Now... my question is.. now that the ObjectiveC XIB classes, etc. are inside the same project, how do I load the XIB? I am an android developer so my iOS imagination is too noob to know what step to take next.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, I assume you are using storyboard for your UI in your Swift application.

As your legacy UI is on XIB files, you need to load it programatically. To do that, you'll have to use `loadNibNamed` method like in the following example :

```
var nibs = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Counter", owner: self, options: nil)
for v in nibs {
    if (v is Counter) {
       someViewInStoryboard.addSubview(v)
   }
}
```

Here I have a Counter.xib file which contains an custom `UIView`. Class for this view is `Counter`, which extends `UIView`.

So when your XIB is loaded, browse it to find your custom view, then add it as a subview of an existing `UIView` in your storyboard. Variable `someViewInStoryboard` in my example is an `IBOutlet` of this `UIView`.